# Check if a process is dead

Tags: python, linux

I know this question has been asked before multiple times. I've tried all of them and failed, that is the reason I'm here again.

Here is what i've tried:

```
pid_foo = "/proc/"+str(fpid[0])
ret = os.path.exists(pid_foo)
if ret == False:
 running = stop
```

next is the follwoing:

```
procs = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
ret = procs.poll()
if ret != None:
 running = stop
```

For the first case, even if the process is dead it keeps executing.
in the second case, I get the following even when the process is dead

```
<bound method Popen.poll of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1f39dd0>>
```

Any idea what is the mistake? or if there is another way to kill the process?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem ? You run a new process with Popen, which seems perfectly fine. Then what ?

Comment: I am not able to know when it is dead

Comment: You can always wait for it to end with `procs.wait()` Or maybe the process is not going to end until you feed it some input, and read its output(so it depends on what command you're executing)

Comment: Could you give me an example? do I just to procs.Wait(fpid) ?

Comment: The process doesn't need any input from the user. Because if i run it on the terminal directly, it is dead after x-min (x>5)

Comment: ``<bound method Popen.poll of...`` seems to be because you do ``ret = procs.poll`` even though you wrote ``ret = procs.poll()`` above.